# Printing East Asian text from database to .txt in Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, encoding

I've got some Eastern Asian text in my database that I'd like to print out to a .txt file.

I've tried File.open(file, "w:utf-8"), but it's unsuccessful. I get broken gibberish instead of the original text.

Example: 한국어 í•œêµ­ì–´

I'm pulling straight from the database, and then writing onto a text. My database is PostgreSQL if it makes any difference.

How I get the text from the database:

```
task :todaysposts => :environment do
  file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/aggs/#{Date.today}.txt", "w:UTF-8")
  videos = Video.where("published_at >= ?", Date.today)
  videos.each do |v|
    file.puts "#{v.title}"
end
end
```

Edit:
Apparently, I was opening the file as ANSI-LATIN-1... It works fine when opened as UTF-8

Comment: Please show how you get the text from the database.

Comment: `I get broken gibberish instead of the original text.` What encoding was the original text written in?  Yes, you have to know the encoding of things you are trying to read!